# ASP.NET Single Worker Thread? (In Memory Session)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, parallel-processing

I'm using in memory sessions in my ASP.NET MVC application which means that I can only have one single worker thread correct? Does this mean I have parallel processing in my application (think concurrent requests) or not? Does my application accept only 1 request at a time?

**Edit**: According to the IIS7 web site:

```
If the application uses in-process session variables, 
the application will not function correctly, because the same user requests 
are picked up by different worker processes that 
do not share the same session details.
```

So this means in-memory session can only have 1 worker thread or not? See also [here](http://forums.iis.net/p/1155444/1894204.aspx#1894204) from the IIS7 forums.

Comment: Processes and threads mean different things in the context of ASP.NET and IIS. Multiple processes mean that you have multiple session stores.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your application receives multiple requests at a time. Based on your edits and comments here you are looking for information on Web Gardens and sessions, as opposed to threads and session state.

Web Gardens use multiple processes and act like a load balancer when it comes to session state. Each process will have a separate in memory session store. IIS will send requests to any available process. Since the processes do not share session state then session usage will only really work if your session provider is shared between all the web garden processes.

Web Gardens only make sense if you use something like SQL Server for session state, and want to have affinity with a particular CPU/core. Since you can increase the number of threads this may be a more appropriate optimization for some users than using web gardens. However some applications may perform better with web gardens due to a particular work load or application characteristic. Use of web gardens in testing could also help work out some potential issues present under load balancing.

I believe it uses the .NET ThreadPool and has 20 threads by default. The each request coming into the server may be handled on a separate thread. The [ASP.NET performance guidelines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms998549.aspx#scalenetchapt06_topic8) have some information on this topic.

Comment: Doesn't this create a problem with the in memory session though? As far as I know the sessions need to stay on the same thread or everything blows up.

Comment: I don't see why threads would be linked to sessions. The Session ID should be enough to lookup the session data so there would be no reason need to map to the same thread. Session data is stored separately even if it is 'in memory'. The same APIs are used to plug in the other session providers.

Comment: Updated the question with quote from IIS7 site & forum link. Supposedly in process (in memory) session doesn't share information across worker threads. Is this wrong info?

Comment: It's the right information but you are not really understanding the nuances here. Processes are different beasts from threads. Web Gardens start multiple processes but IIS maps every request through. This pretty much simulates a load-balanced environment. Hence the processes have separate session state but the end user could end up hitting either process on the next request.

Comment: +1 thanks for the explanation Brian. Does it make sense to have web gardens then on one server? When one could just increase the worker THREAD count of the single IIS process?

Comment: I added some info on situations for web gardens. It's hard to think of reasons. Most people tend to ignore them since they could make performance worse, or they are scared of session problems with off-the-shelf applications that they don't want to test fully.

Comment: The answer is correct, but I wanted to add that you can use web garden scenarios without using SqlServer as session store. By simply setting up a **Windows AppFabric Cache** instance (or any similar caching solution). Its basically a separate service that handles your caching outside of your individual processes. This way you can **share your cache across processes or even servers**. And there are SessionState/Output cache providers that plug directly into the "external" AppFabric cache. Get started here:  
http://bit.ly/enWpQO

Answer (score -1):

In memory sessions means you should typically only have one front-end web **server** at a time, not a single worker thread :D

The reason being that any information stored in session on one machine is not available on the other. If you have two front-end web servers and your proxy or firewall does "load-balancing" whereby it will randomly assign requests to web servers, then you will have problems. That said, the problem is easily solved with so called "sticky sessions" where users are always sent to the same server.

-Oisin

Comment: Follow Up: Why can't you enable 'web garden' processing on your machine then across multiple CPU on one server? This causes random session loss.

Comment: My understanding is that a web garden creates multiple processes on a machine. Each process will have a different session state store.